# How to show a record if the record is not in a file

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report, I have a 2 files.

File A (Order File) & File B (Notes File)

They are linked between the Order # which is in both files but not every order is in File B because not every order has a note

The issue with this is that when I put my fields onto the report, some orders do not show on my report because there is no note for it in File B. How do I get the order to show on my report, regardless if there is a note in file B.

Comment: Sounds like you are using an inner join (link) between the tables. You should be using a Left join from File A to File B

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. So my join type should be Left Outer Join and then my enforce join should be not enforced?